# How to start msaccess database from command line in java?

Tags: java, file, runtime, command-line-arguments

I'm working on a database-related project and i have a MS-Access Database located at:

`D:\My Documents\Database.accdb`

So i use the following command for running MS-Access:

`cmd /c start MSACCESS D:\My Documents\database.accdb`

In java:

```
view.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent E) {
        String[] command = {"cmd", "/c", "start MSACCESS D:\\My Documents\\Database.accdb"}
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    }
});
```

Microsoft Access inmediatly starts but throws the following error:

"The command line you used to start Microsoft Office Access contains an option that Micosoft Access doesn't recognize"

And then:

"The database file 'D:\My.mdb' cannot be found"

So i assumed that it doesn't recognise the space at: "My Documents" and it truncates at "My", so i try it's NTFS 8.3 equivalent: D:\MYDOCU~1\Database.accdb, and throws:

"The database file 'D:\MYDOCU~1\Database.accdb' cannot be found"

I really don't know whats wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"D:\My Documents\Database.accdb" contains a space and is being treated as an additional parameter (so it would like like `{"cmd", "/c", "start", "MSACCESS", "D:\\My", "Documents\\Database.accdb"}` to the calling program)

Use something like

```
String[] command = {"cmd", "/c", "start", "MSACCESS", "D:\\My Documents\\Database.accdb"};
```

instead...

**UPDATE**

Trying to "shorten" the path names manually is very dangerous and ill advised.  If you need to go this route, you really should take advantage of a native call to the OS to tell how the name should be shortened, so both you and the OS know that you're talking about the same thing

**ADDITIONAL**

Also, try running the command from the command prompt just to make sure it works ;)

Comment: Actually i lost some effort building an algorithm to convert long name dirs to ntfs8.3 dirs following the steps described at microsoft support website: http://pastebin.com/9pChjjFF (It's a disaster code)

But it was just a silly mistake. Thanks!

Comment: @JorgeChayan Wow 8O - I just accessed the built in method via a JNI layer :P

Comment: About the adittional, that's what was blowing my mind, it worked at command prompt, but didn't work from the code because of not separating the arguments correctly Dx

Comment: Lol, actually the JNA Library contains a method to do the conversion, but doesn't work for large filenames, i also tried it

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
String[] command = {"cmd", "/c", "start \"MSACCESS D:\\My Documents\\Database.accdb\""}
```

PS: I don't know about your project, but depending on what you want to do with the database, it could make sense to open it as a "normal" SQL database via JDBC instead. Post another question if you'd like to do that and have trouble with the connection string.

Comment: Yeah i did lots of sql queries, but i just wanted to add an extra option that allows to open the database from the program. Greetings!

Comment: "jdbc:odbc:DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb);DBQ=" + path;

Comment: @Jorge: Yes, that works, but in my experience you're running into lots of trouble if not also specifying `ExtendedAnsiSQL=1`.